# R: referring to colnames within a function

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I want to apply a function to all columns of a dataframe. Within that function, I want to use the respective colnames. However, these are lost - how do I keep them, or otherwise refer to them within the function?

```
data <- data.frame("A" = rnorm(500, 0, 1), 
                   "B" = rnorm(500, 0, 1))

funk <- function(x,...){
  paste(colnames(x), " & ", round(mean(x, na.rm = T), 1), sep = "")
}

lapply(data, funk)
```

Gives:

```
$A
[1] " & -0.1"

$B
[1] " & 0.1"
```

But I want:

```
$A
[1] "A & -0.1"

$B
[1] "B & 0.1"
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a `lapply` if you use `colMeans` instead of `mean`:

```
   funk <- function(x,...){
     paste(colnames(x), " & ", round(colMeans(x, na.rm = T), 1), sep = "")
   }
```

And then just:

```
  funk(data)
```

Edit: the above will give you a simple `character` vector as output. If you want a `list` with names as per your desired output, just define `funk` as follow:

```
  funk <- function(x,...){
     setNames(as.list(paste(colnames(x), " & ", round(colMeans(x, na.rm = T), 1), sep = "")),names(x))
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but the mean() is trivial. Its about pasting the colname to the output of any function on the column.

Answer (score 2):

Since `paste` is vectorized, you can use `colMeans` with it and not have to loop anything.

```
paste(names(data), " & ", round(colMeans(data), 1))
```

So I'd probably write the function like this:

```
funk <- function(x, digits = 1L, na.rm = TRUE) {
    means <- round(colMeans(x, na.rm = na.rm), digits = digits)
    setNames(as.list(paste(names(x), " & ", means)), names(x))
}
funk(data)
# $A
# [1] "A  &  0"
#
# $B
# [1] "B  &  0"

funk(data, digits = 3)
# $A
# [1] "A  &  0.023"
#
# $B
# [1] "B  &  -0.046"
```

But from your comment it seems like you might be wondering how to apply the names one-to-one *while* you're applying a function.  For that you might want to look at `Map` and/or `mapply`

```
Map(paste, names(data), " & ", round(colMeans(data), 3))
# $A
# [1] "A  &  0.023"
#
# $B
# [1] "B  &  -0.046"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
lapply(seq_len(ncol(data)), function(i) 
    paste(colnames(data[i]), " & " , round(mean(data[,i], 
                                      na.rm=TRUE), 1), sep=""))
```